# MFC on form create event

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have simple FMC dialog form. Can't find how to manage event that should be called on form create moment. Something like onFormCreate like it is in VB or Delphi.

How to create such functionality?

My simple form header:

```
#pragma once


// CMFCApplicationUPTDlg dialog
class CMFCApplicationUPTDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CMFCApplicationUPTDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);    // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFCAPPLICATIONUPT_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
};
```

Comment: hint `virtual BOOL OnInitDialog`

Comment: As this is not a VB or Delphi question, you'd have to explain what do you mean by "form create moment". Window is created? All controls are initialized? The whole thing is visible?

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle it in the OnInitDialog() member function.  At the point that OnInitDialog() is called, the dialog and all of its child windows will have been created.  However, the dialog will still be invisible to the user.  After exiting OnInitDialog(), the dialog will be shown to the user.

So, it is the place where you would want to do initialization of your dialog.

Comment: To add to this, at the point your own OnInitDialog is call, the dialog is not yet created, you need to call the base class OnInitDialog before accessing the dialog content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement OnInitDialog in your own derived class.

```
BOOL CMFCApplicationUPTDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  // this will create the controls you defined in the resources.
  BOOL retValue = __super::OnInitDialog();

  // initialize (or add new controls to ) your dialog content here.
  // ...
  return retValue;
}
```